# Ember-plupload disable multiple file upload not working

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, plupload

I am using ember 2.5.0.In my application i am having file upload functionality.Using following api [Ember-plupload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-plupload) for file upload. Able to upload a file but i want user to upload only one file, as per documentation setting **multiple="false"** should disable selecting multiple file options, but it is not disabling instead it is adding the file in a queue. Could anyone faced the similar problem?

Also it would be great if some one share the code snippet for removing file from queue.

```
{{#pl-uploader extensions="jpg" multiple="false" for="upload-image" onfileadd="uploadImage"}}
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Choose file to import</label> <br/>
    <div class="dropzone" id="upload-image" style="width: 80%; height: 100px; border: 2px dashed gray; padding: 0 20px">
        <p>
      <br/>
      {{#if fileInfo}}<div class="alert alert-success">{{fileInfo}}</div>{{/if}}
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

{{/pl-uploader}}

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to set multiple to false as boolean not "false" as string. So just change multiple="false" to multiple=false